# How can I check whether a browser window/tab is focused?

Tags: javascript, flash, browser

I know the window.blur / focus solution.

Can't use it.

It is a small widget. It lives in an iframe, and because of this, this method is not working. And since the iframe is loaded from a different domain there is no way to reach the top level window object.

Here: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showpost.php3?p=1078962&postcount=5

> "With the recent new 10.3 player this should be much easier, since there are new events for this specific situation."

So, using a simple flash object, and maybe js callbacks this might be the solution, but what are theese events? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, but you might want to take a look at the [Page Visibility API](http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility.html). (I've also built a [simple demo](http://samdutton.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/the-page-visibility-api/).)

What are you trying to do when the window/tab gets focus?

Can window.postMessage help you? (See [this post](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/) for discussion of backwards compatible alternatives.)

Comment: This could be a good solution, but we need something that works in IE6 too :(

Comment: Yeah -- thought that might be the case :(. See answer for additional suggestion :).

Comment: This is half solution. Actually the problem is that my widget is inside an iframe, and I can only modify contents of this iframe, not the whole page. So there is no way to implement a message event listener outside of the iframe.

Comment: This may not answer your question, but you might want to take a look at Mike Mahemoff's post on communication with iframes: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn’t helpful in general, but new versions of Firefox and Chrome reduce the setInterval timing to a maximum of one poll per second in background tabs. You could probably rig up an increment checker that compares a variable incrementing in a setInterval loop against a start Date / end Date value.